# "incorrect PK" : delete operation on CrudRepository for entity annotated with @IdClass

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

## Context

When my service calls `repository.delete(myEntity)`, I get the following error:

> 105 | You have provided an instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.  **Class expected : class com.foo.PrimaryKey, Class received : class java.lang.String**.

The repository interface `extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, PrimaryKey>`.

I use `@IdClass(PrimaryKey.class)` on my `@Entity` class and have labeled the relevant individual fields with `@Id`. **There is a single field in the `PrimaryKey`, and it's a `String`**. We do this to keep our codebase consistent so that every `@Entity` always declares its primary key as a composite key.

### My own analysis (could be wrong)

For some reason, JPA internally calls `em.find(MyEntity.class, primaryKeyString)` instead of building a `PrimaryKey` instance from that String and using it, hence the error.

The same error happens when I try to call `repository.deleteById(correspondingPrimaryKeyInstance)` instead.

#### Framework code

This comes from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`, and I added a comment where things fail:

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void delete(T entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null!");

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            return;
        }

        Class<?> type = ProxyUtils.getUserClass(entity);

        T existing = (T) em.find(type, entityInformation.getId(entity)); // IT FAILS HERE... `entityInformation.getId(entity)` returns a String instead of the expected `PrimaryKey`

        // if the entity to be deleted doesn't exist, delete is a NOOP
        if (existing == null) {
            return;
        }

        em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
    }
```

## Code

- Repository:

```java
public interface MyEntityCRUDRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, PrimaryKey> { }
public interface MyEntityCustomRepository { /* some custom operations */ }

@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends MyEntityCRUDRepository, MyEntityCustomRepository { }
```

- Service:

```java
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyEntityService {
    private final MyEntityRepository repository;

    public void destroy(final PrimaryKey pk) {
//        repository.deleteById(pk); // also returns the error
        MyEntity myEntity = repository.findById(pk)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(DOES_NOT_EXIST));
        repository.delete(myEntity); // returns the error
    }
}
```

- JPA entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@IdClass(PrimaryKey.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "the_id", updatable = false)
    private String theId;

    // other fields which aren't part of the primary key
}
```

- Primary key class:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
    private String theId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in `Spring Data`. See the related (now solved) issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2330.

One of the maintainers said:

> Another workaround is to let your entities implement `Persistable`.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix: don't use `@IdClass` when you have only a single attribute that is the ID.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
//@IdClass(PrimaryKey.class)
public class TemporaryReservation {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "the_id", updatable = false)
    private String theId;

    // other fields which aren't part of the primary key
}
```

```java
public interface MyEntityCRUDRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> { }
```

Once that's changed, make the appropriate adjustments in the rest of the code.